# Is there a shared lead AND Gate IC?

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, integrated-circuit

Hi I'm an electronics hobbyist still learning some basics of digital logic.

I'm looking into building an arduino shield, but I want the arduino pinouts I'm using to be accessible when the shield is not enabled(by a single control pin). I know I could just wire up one lead of each of the gates 74HC08 to the enable line, but I'm wondering if there is a more convenient form factor for this kind of application, as the pins are somewhat awkwardly positioned.  For example is there an IC where i[n] is passed to o[n] if enable is set?

```
EN o0  o1  o2

|___|___|___| 
|           |
|___________|
|   |   |   |
GND i0 i1  i2
```

To clarify, I'm not looking for a specific product, rather I assume this is a common problem, and would like to know what keywords to use to find such a device.

Comment: Do you mean a buffer? 74**541, for one of many examples? https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/74/74AC541.pdf Or 244? http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT244.pdf

Comment: (1) No Vcc on your pinout.  (2) There are quad buffers with one common enable.  (3) Questions seeking recommendations for specific products are off-topic on EE.SE .

Comment: There are all sorts of bidirectional bus switch chips that you can get.  74CBT3245, for example.  8 channels of bidirectional I/O with an enable pin.  It also doubles as a level translator for interfacing 5v and 3.3v logic.

Comment: While perhaps overkill for your specific problem, you  might find it interesting to look into CPLD's.  If you look hard enough you may still be able to find some 5v ones.  Typically they cost around a dollar in singles - though the real cost is writing the hdl code and dealing with the toolchain and programming.

Comment: It seems what I'm looking fore is called "buffer" or bus switch.  Thank you for examples of serial numbers as well, I really just needed to know the device type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use a pullup or pulldown, the 74XX125 and [similar devices](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/logic/non-inverting-buffer-driver-products.page#p1512=AC;AHC;ACT;HC;HCT;LVC) will reflect the inputs on their outputs if the enable line is asserted, and go high-impedance if deasserted.

Comment: Yes this seems to be the case, the device I need seems to commonly be called a buffer, and the function I want is called bus switching.